# How to do dynamic nested query with rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I would like to create the following query in rails

this is data in database(mysql)

```
id parent_id
1   
10   1
100  10
101  10
1001 101
```

This is the logic I want to do

```
select(1) -> result 1,10,100,101,1001
select(10) -> result 10,100,101,1001
select(100) -> result 10
select(101) -> result 101,1001
```

I Want to get all columns that have parent_id corresponding to the argument

But I don't know how to do it. if you have any idean, pleas let me know

Comment: hmm.. `select id from tbl where id like '10%'` for `select(10)`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I'm not sure about MySQL but PG definitely wont let you use LIKE on a int/bigint - so you have to cast it with `select cast(id as varchar) from tbl where id like '10%'`

Comment: @max MySQL will cast implicitly. But if those are ints - no index can be used for LIKE. I might then rather write a recursive query. However - I don't want to put more into this question, without knowing, what it is about.